# PHP connects but cannot query MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am querying a mysql database with php but cannot get it to work on my iMac. In particular, php is unable to connect to the mysql DB. It connects to mysql and selects the DB but then fails. See code below:

```
if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd)){
    die("I cannot connect to database");
}
if (!mysql_select_db($database)){
    die("I cannot select database");
}

$sql = "SELECT FROM ${table} ORDER BY $sql_orderBy";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die("I cannot execute query to show fields from Table: {$table}. Query failed.");
}
```

For reference, I installed apache/mysql/php with macports. The same php code works on my laptop (same installations), and the query works when I invoke it from within mysql on both computers. All variables are declared. Something with the system config is my best guess, but I even went through a uninstall/install.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what is `${table}` ? This should be {$table} or better still, `".$table."`

Comment: also DO NOT USE MySQL as it is ***deprecated*** . Instead spend an afternoon reading up on MySQLi or PDO, they are more secure and currently supported by PHP

Comment: Remove `{` and `}` from `${table}`, which is a variable variable of a Constant.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is `${table}` . This should be {$table} or better still, ".$table."

You also need to say what you are *SELECTING*: 
So:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." ORDER BY ".$sql_orderBy;
```

You can discover issues by using `Mysql_error()` at the end of the query, for example:

```
mysql_query($sqlString) or die("line: ".__LINE__.":".mysql_error());
```

this will output a clear error message regarding your SQL statement. This is not for production and public situations but for development.

Also:

MySQL is ***deprecated*** and is no longer supported by PHP or the wider community, it is VERY strongly recommended you take up MySQLi or PDO and use these methods as they are much stronger, less flawed and more efficient delivery of results. They will also be supported in future updates and developments whereas MySQL will not.